# Search for assets containing a custom field

Tags: templating, assets, search, assetfilemodel

How can I search for assets containing a custom field? The field on the asset is called **lang**. When I use this code no assets are found.

```
{% set folderId = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('folderId') %}
{% set query = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('q') %}
{% set lang = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('lang') %}

{# Search for assets in the downlaoads folder #}
{% set assets = craft.assets().volume('downloads') %}
{% set assets = assets.folderId(folderId).includeSubFolders() %}

{% set searchQuery = [] %}

{# Check if a query was supplied, if so then search for it. #}
{% if query is not empty %}
{%     set searchQuery = searchQuery|merge({query: query}) %}
{% endif %}

{% if lang is not empty %}
{%   set searchQuery = searchQuery|merge({query: 'lang:' ~ lang}) %}
{% endif %}

{% paginate assets.search(searchQuery).limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

I also tried:

```
{% set query = query ~ ' lang: ' ~lang %}
{% paginate assets.search(query).limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

If I remove the lang part results will show up.

The field is a Dropdown field with languages. Value is ISO code and Label the language name. The variable lang in the code contains nl, en etc.

Comment: Is your custom field searchable?

Comment: I checked 'Use this field’s values as search keywords' but that didn't help. The field is a Dropdown field with languages. Value is ISO code and Label the language name. The variable lang in the code contains nl, en etc.

Comment: If your values are known/fixed then I'd consider adding that as an element query, then searching on the results of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caveat**: This is totally untested, and could be nonsense. I'm sure you'll let me know. It assumes that the [Craft element query](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#executing-element-queries) methods can be used here.

If you have a 'lang' value, add a *where* to your basic assets element query

```
    {% set folderId = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('folderId') %}
    {% set query = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('q') %}
    {% set lang = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('lang') %}
    
    {# Search for assets in the downloads folder #}
    {% set assetsQuery = craft.assets().volume('downloads') %}
    {% set assetsQuery = assets.folderId(folderId).includeSubFolders() %}

    {# If there's a lang value, add a where to the element query #}
    {% if lang is not empty %}
    {%     set assetsQuery = assetsQuery.where(expression('[[field_lang]] = :lang', {lang: lang})) %}
    {% endif %}
    
    {% set searchQuery = [] %}

    {# Check if a query was supplied, if so then search for it. #}
    {% if query is not empty %}
    {%     set searchQuery = searchQuery|merge({query: query}) %}
    {% endif %}
    
    {% paginate assetsQuery.search(searchQuery).limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

*Note that I've changed the variable 'assets' to 'assetsQuery'

Comment: Got an exception Twig\Error\SyntaxError: An array element must be followed by a comma. Unexpected token "arrow function" of value "=>" ("punctuation" expected with value ","). Looks like the arrow function in the where clause isn't allowed. We are on Craft version 3.6.13

Comment: Looks like it needs to be an [Expression](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#expression), so try
`set assetsQuery = assetsQuery.where( expression('[[lang]] = :lang', {lang: lang}) );`

Comment: Thanks Andy, this is working great. Had to change [[lang]] to [[field_lang]] and it worked.